# Export pytorch model parameters into separate files according to layer hierarchy

Tags: python, pytorch

Is it possible to export the trained parameters of a Pytorch model into separate binary files (float32/64, not text) under a folder hierarchy reflecting the layers defined by the model's architecture?

I wish to examine a sizeable pretrained model without the framework overhead and also split the checkpoint into manageable chunks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do this, but it should take only a few lines of code. For example, consider I have a model of the following structure:

```
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, C_in, C_out, kernel, pool):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(C_in, C_out, kernel)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace = True)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2) if pool else nn.Identity()
        
    def forward(self, input):
        out = self.conv(input)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.pool(out)
        return out
    
class LeNet5(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.block1 = ConvBlock(1, 6, 5, pool = True)
        self.block2 = ConvBlock(6, 16, 5, pool = True)
        self.block3 = ConvBlock(16, 120, 5, pool = False)
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(120, 84),
            nn.ReLU(inplace = True),
            nn.Linear(84, 10)
        )
        
    def forward(self, input):
        out = self.block1(input)
        out = self.block2(out)
        out = self.block3(out)
        out = out.view(-1,120)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
```

To binarize individual parameters, all you have to do is iterate through them.

```
net = LeNet5()

basedir = 'lenet_params'

for name, param in net.named_parameters():
    name = name.split('.')
    out_dir, filename = os.path.join(basedir, *name[:-1]), name[-1]+'.pth'
    out_path = os.path.join(out_dir, filename)

    if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
        os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)
    torch.save(param, out_path)
```

This will produce the directory structure below:

```
lenet_params
|---block1
|   |---conv
|   |   |---weight.pth
|   |   |---bias.pth
|---block2
|   |---conv
|   |   |---weight.pth
|   |   |---bias.pth
|---block3
|   |---conv
|   |   |---weight.pth
|   |   |---bias.pth
|---fc
|   |---0
|   |   |---weight.pth
|   |   |---bias.pth
|   |---2
|   |   |---weight.pth
|   |   |---bias.pth
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a good starting point. I will test this tomorrow and try to parse the raw values. If there are no stumbling blocks I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It works with a bit of overhead, each .pkl is a zipfile containing `archive/data.pkl` (serialized dict_struct), `archive/version` (3) and `archive/data/<numericname>` (raw data). Saving only the last bit would be ideal, but at least I can avoid parsing data.pkl

Comment: My Python knowledge is rather basic, `f.write(param.data)` does not work, is there some way to serialize it?

Comment: f.write(s) requires s to be a string; param.data is a tensor. To try writing a tensor in binary mode, I would suggest: `with open('filename.dat','wb+') as f: f.write(param.data.numpy().tobytes())`. You need to open the file in binary mode and of course, serialize it into a bytes object with .numpy().tobytes().